# need text below imagebutton

Tags: java, android-imagebutton

I have a Imagebutton. I want text to be displayed at the bottom of the image. so, i created a Frame Layout. I placed the imagebutton and a text view inside that. But when i run the code on device, the text overlaps the button. It is not shown at the bottom of the image. How to solve this?I have 3 image buttons. All of them are placed inside a linear layout.
code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="fill_horizontal" android:layout_margin="0dp">

    <FrameLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="fill_vertical" android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"

            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="scan ticket"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tv_question"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tv_question"
            android:background="#00ffffff"
            android:src="@drawable/scan_ticket"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="scan ticket" >
        </TextView>
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="fill_vertical" android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="scan and pay"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tv_question"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tv_question"
            android:background="#00ffffff"
            android:src="@drawable/scan_and_pay"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="scan and pay" >
        </TextView>
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="fill_vertical" android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="bank transfer"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tv_question"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tv_question"
            android:background="#00ffffff"
            android:src="@drawable/bank_transfer"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="bank transfer" >
        </TextView>
    </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you use kotlin or java?

Comment: I use java not kotlin

Answer (score 0):

ConstraintLayout will be very helpful for your problem. You can locate elements by others.
Here is the documentation: [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout)

Comment: how to use constraint layout. I could not use. see edits

Answer (score 0):

done using android:layout_marginBottom and android:layout_marginTop as shown in the code.
Problem faced: the image shown in imagebutton is not the full image
But I managed now manipulating android:layout_marginBottom and android:layout_marginTop in ImageButton and TextView

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:padding="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="fill_horizontal" android:layout_margin="0dp">

<FrameLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="fill_vertical" android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="scan ticket"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tv_question"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tv_question"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:src="@drawable/scan_ticket"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="scan and pay" >
    </TextView>
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="fill_vertical" android:layout_margin="10dp">

<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="scan and pay"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tv_question"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tv_question"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:src="@drawable/scan_and_pay"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="scan and pay" >
    </TextView>
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="fill_vertical" android:layout_margin="10dp">

<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="bank transfer"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tv_question"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tv_question"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:src="@drawable/bank_transfer"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="bank transfer" >
    </TextView>
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```